# Formula that needs to return information based on two criterias

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, r-googlesheets

I have reached a roadblock when it comes to a formula that we are currently working on for works purposes.

What the formula needs to achieve is bring back information based on two cells' information. We have gotten it to work with one cell using  the following formula:

```
"CONCATENATE(INDEX(IF(sheet2!c:c = c1, "company: " & char(10, ""))))"
```

Now this brings back some information but not as defined as we would like it to be, so we need to bring in a second cell, using

```
"IF(sheet2!c:c = c1 & ..."
```

brings back no results, leaving the cell empty. Using `IFS` produces either an error or name, as does `AND(, OR(, MATCH(, CHOOSE(`.

Any of your learned input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is unusual. try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Sheet2!C:C=C1)*(Sheet2!D:D=D1), "company: "&CHAR(10), ))
```

or with `+` mimicking `OR`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Sheet2!C:C=C1)+(Sheet2!D:D=D1), "company: "&CHAR(10), ))
```